# SQL Server : ORDER BY CASE ignored

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a SQL statement with `ORDER BY CASE` something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCTS
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN StockQuantity > 0 THEN 1
        WHEN OutOfStockOrder = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END, _Ranking DESC, Name, ProductId
```

Records are ordered correctly with `CASE`; the first records with 1(StockQuantity > 0 OR OutOfStockOrder = 1) then record with 0. Also, records with CASE 1 (StockQuantity > 0 OR OutOfStockOrder = 1) are then ordered correctly with _Ranking, then Name and finally ProductId. But, when CASE are 0, _Ranking are not used by order; records are ordered only for Name and then ProductId.

Like this:

```
ProductId | Name     | StockQuantity | OutOfStockOrder | _Ranking
----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+-----------
15        | Camera   |  10           | 0               | 50
25        | Mouse    |  5            | 1               | 25
10        | Keyboard |  1            | 0               | 5
50        | Ball     |  0            | 0               | 0
60        | IPad     |  0            | 0               | 35
```

Is there something I missed?

I'm using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: That `order by` cannot produce those results because the *first* key is wrong.  It says that `StockQuantity > 0` goes *second* not *first*.

Comment: What I need is to have all records that have stock quantity >0 or OutOfStockOrder first then order by ranking, name and productID. That order by is the result of query on my db.

Comment: Yes but _Ranking DESC so 35 before 0.

Comment: When in doubt, add the `case` _expression_ to the `SELECT` list too - and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: `0` comes before `1`. I'd expect to see `(IPad, Ball, Camera, Mouse, Keyboard)` in that order for this data with that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your `CASE` expression so that rows with `StockQuantity > 0 OR OutOfStockOrder = 1` are returned first.
The rest of the query is correct:

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCTS
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN StockQuantity > 0 OR OutOfStockOrder = 1 THEN 0
           ELSE 1
         END, 
         _Ranking DESC,
         Name, 
         ProductId
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e305b767ad43b0c673b2f604fbb88a5b).
Results:

| ProductId | Name | StockQuantity | OutOfStockOrder | _Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Camera | 10 | 0 | 50 |
| 25 | Mouse | 5 | 1 | 25 |
| 10 | Keyboard | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 60 | IPad | 0 | 0 | 35 |
| 50 | Ball | 0 | 0 | 0 |